# CSS set rules based on left position?

Tags: css

Is it possible to set rules in CSS to do something like :

```
.some_div_class[left < 700]{    
      display:block;
}
```

Obviously this doens't work..

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? If the class is less than 700px to the left, then apply the css rule?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do in pure CSS

Comment: It's difficult to give you a concrete answer without seeing any code. But if your problem involve different screen sizes, you can use css media queries to apply different css rule.

Comment: CSS doesn't do "if" statements logic

Comment: @Hayder, I know, I'm already using them, but for some switches between block and inline-block to fit the display, I have to deal with margins. I'm trying to remove margins if an elements is positioned on the right side of its container.

Comment: @frenchie, it does selection by attribute tho it kind of does "if" when you specify and attribute and a value to look for...

Comment: it seems that a css selector that you like to use, only works on actual attributes that are in the html. In your case, the 'left' attribute is dynamic, right? So this is probably not gonna work. I think media queries is the only solution here. I don't have much experience with them, maybe http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ can help you?

Comment: Well what if i create an attribute like posx and update its value every 500 ms, would I be able to compare it ?

Comment: Could you not give a class to the elements that will be in that position, and then control them through that?

Comment: no because they get display:block or display:inline-block depending on their container size. I'm trying to avoid doing that in JS 'on resize'

Answer (score -1):

No, but in jQuery :

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(".some_div_class").position().left<700)
        $(".some_div_class").css({display: "block"});
});
```

Comment: $('.some_div_class').each(... maybe ? :)